# Can I use vray materials, lights, camera and other render setting in 3D MAX by exporting model with GLTF format to use in THREE.JS?

Tags: three.js, render, gltf, 3dsmax, pbr

As you know GLTF format supports PBR standard rendering settings. I would like to know What is the best render engine can I use in 3D MAX to make effective GLTF export for using in THREE.js. Especially, vray is a good choice or not? Thanks all

I want to have fewer and fewer material and light settings in THREE.js. Because naturally, we have better and more effective tools in 3D MAX and VRAY environment.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of a renderer in 3ds Max will not have much, if any, impact on the resulting glTF file and three.js scene. 3ds Max 2023 adds a glTF exporter, which depends mainly on use of the new [glTF Material](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-7ABFB805-1D9F-417E-9C22-704BFDF160FA). With any other material type, exporting correctly will be a rough approximation at best.

In any case, you will probably want set up your lighting in three.js. It's extremely difficult to move lighting between modeling tools and engines reliably, unless you're using image-based lighting like an OpenEXR or HDR environment map.

You might also consider doing most of your modeling in 3ds Max, but doing final touches to materials in [Gestaltor](https://gestaltor.io/). It has the advantage of having been designed ground-up around the glTF format, supports nearly every feature of glTF, and will provide very consistent results when you load your scene in three.js.

Comment: Thank you very much @Don for your Answer. I visited Gestaltor website. That sounds wonderful. However, I decided to use this method: I create my model in 3D MAX. Then making render by VRAY. After that I make baked-textures. finally export to GLTF format for use in THREE.JS and using baked textures. So, I would have the least setting for lights, materials, textures and other things in THREE.JS. What is your opinion about this work flow?

Comment: I would expect that your results in Vray will look very different from your results in three.js using that workflow, unless you can also use the glTF Material in 3ds Max 2023. Lights created in 3ds Max will not look the same in three.js, in any case. The viewport renderer in 3ds Max has no effect on the data exported to three.js. If the workflow is working in a way you're happy enough with though, that's great!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints. I'll let you know the result.